# Redux reducer adds to array instead of overwriting it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux store set up with 1 array object. I have written a reducer to update the store by replacing the existing array with the new one. For some reason the reducer seems to add to the existing array instead of replacing it. Any ideas why this is occuring?

```
const initState = {
    articles: [
        {key: 1, title: "ggg", content: "sfsdfdsf"},
        {key: 2, title: "gdffgg", content: "rgkrdpo"},
        {key: 3, title: "gfsgg", content: "s;flksd;fl"}
    ]
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "UPDATE_ARTICLES"){
        var newArticles = action.newArticles;
        return{
            articles: newArticles
        };
    }else{
        return state
    }
}


export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Show the code that prepares and dispatches the action. How is `action.newArticles` being created?  Where is the update coming from, and how is it being put together?

Comment: If you don't mind you can give more details.

Comment: can you show the "UPDATE_ARTICLES" action code?

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the state in your reducer every time.

```
return {    ...state,
            articles: newArticles
        };
```

Comment: If you're changing the whole state of the reducer as it is happening in this case then there is no need to copy the previous state.